# Ajax request for database lookup

Tags: php, ajax

I have a site that logs a user in and does a db lookup to see if the user has acknowledged that they have read a file. If they have not they are sent to a page with links to the files which need to be read. Once they read the file and click the acknowledge link the php script adds this file name along with user name to a table named read. What I want to do is stop the user from navigating away from this page if they have not acknowledged that they read the files. How would I use the javascript onunload function and do an ajax request to check if they have read the files that need to be read. I am new to ajax so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since it is a company site I am assumming they are not to turn off the js since it was originally written with js and php. They are having problems with their employees not clicking the link. I did not write this application I was asked to take a look at it and see if something can be done. If there is another way of doing this I am all ears.

Comment: Add a check box at the bottom of the page you want the person to read. If checked, the user has indicated they have read the page. It's similar to a TOS check box on most sites. Pass the data via `$_POST` and store the response in the database.

Comment: the page has an acknowledge link on it that the user must click to acknowledged they have read the file whcich is in pdf format. When they click the link a javascript function is called and id of the file is sent to php script which updates the database with the file id, name and username and that indicates they have read the file. The issue is keeping them from navigating away until they click the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to handle this is PHP, not JS. Too easy to get around it if you depend on JS:

1) when loading the user data into the session, check if they acknowledged it or not.

2) add a condition to fire on every page load (same place in the code where you check if they are logged in) in php that will redirect them to that page unless they have acknowledged it.